# Why does LogisticRegression fail with "IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7"?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run simple logistic regression program in spark.
I am getting this error: I tried to include various libs for solving the problem  but it is not solving the problem.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column pmi
>   must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was
>   actually DoubleType.

This is my dataSet csv

```
abc,pmi,sv,h,rh,label
0,4.267034,5,1.618187,5.213683,T
0,4.533071,24,3.540976,5.010458,F
0,6.357766,7,0.440152,5.592032,T
0,4.694365,1,0,6.953864,T
0,3.099447,2,0.994779,7.219463,F
0,1.482493,20,3.221419,7.219463,T
0,4.886681,4,0.919705,5.213683,F
0,1.515939,20,3.92588,6.329699,T
0,2.756057,9,2.841345,6.727063,T
0,3.341671,13,3.022361,5.601656,F
0,4.509981,7,1.538982,6.716471,T
0,4.039118,17,3.206316,6.392757,F
0,3.862023,16,3.268327,4.080564,F
0,5.026574,1,0,6.254859,T
0,3.186627,19,1.880978,8.466048,T
1,6.036507,8,1.376031,4.080564,F
1,5.026574,1,0,6.254859,T
1,-0.936022,23,2.78176,5.601656,F
1,6.435599,3,1.298795,3.408575,T
1,4.769222,3,1.251629,7.201824,F
1,3.190702,20,3.294354,6.716471,F
```

This is the Edited Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler;

    public class Sp_LogistcRegression {
        public void trainLogisticregression(String path, String model_path) throws IOException {
            //SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Linear Regression Example");
            //  JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Sp_LogistcRegression").master("local[6]").config("spark.driver.memory", "3G").getOrCreate();
             Dataset<Row> training = spark
                    .read()
                    .option("header", "true")
                    .option("inferSchema","true")
                    .csv(path);
             String[] myStrings = {"abc", 
                     "pmi", "sv",   "h",    "rh",   "label"};


             VectorAssembler  VA = new  VectorAssembler().setInputCols(myStrings ).setOutputCol("label");
             Dataset<Row> transform = VA.transform(training);

            LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(1000).setRegParam(0.3);


            LogisticRegressionModel lrModel = lr.fit( transform);
            lrModel.save(model_path);

            spark.close();

        }

    }
```

This is the test.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Sp_LogistcRegressionTest {
    Sp_LogistcRegression spl =new Sp_LogistcRegression ();


    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {

        String filename = "datas/seg-large.csv";
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file1 = new File(classLoader.getResource(filename).getFile());
        spl. trainLogisticregression( file1.getAbsolutePath(), "/tmp");

    }    
}
```

**UPDATE** 
As per your suggestion, I removed the string value attribute form the the dataset, which is label. Now, I get following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:51)
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Use [VectorAssembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler) transformer.

Spark MLlib's `LogisticRegression` requires features column to be of type `VectorUDT` (as the error message says).

In your Spark application, you read the dataset from a CSV file and the field you use for features is of different type.

Please note that I can use Spark MLlib not necessarily explain what Machine Learning as a field of study would recommend in this case.

My recommendation would then be to use a transformer that would map the column to match the requirements of `LogisticRegression`.

A quick glance at the [known transformers in Spark MLlib 2.1.1](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer) gives me [VectorAssembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler).

> A feature transformer that merges multiple columns into a vector column.

That's exactly what you need.

(I use Scala and I leave rewriting the code to Java as your home exercise)

```
val training: DataFrame = ...

// the following are to show that we're on the same page
val lr = new LogisticRegression().setFeaturesCol("pmi")
scala> lr.fit(training)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column pmi must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually IntegerType.
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:51)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.Classifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ProbabilisticClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$LogisticRegressionParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:265)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:100)
  ... 48 elided
```

*"Houston, we've got a problem."* Let's fix it by using `VectorAssembler` then.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
val vecAssembler = new VectorAssembler().
  setInputCols(Array("pmi")).
  setOutputCol("features")
val features = vecAssembler.transform(training)
scala> features.show
+---+--------+
|pmi|features|
+---+--------+
|  5|   [5.0]|
| 24|  [24.0]|
+---+--------+

scala> features.printSchema
root
 |-- pmi: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

Whoohoo! We've got `features` column of the proper `vector` type! Are we done?

Yes. In my case however as I use `spark-shell` for the experimentation, it won't work right away since `lr` uses a wrong `pmi` column (i.e. of incorrect type).

```
scala> lr.fit(features)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column pmi must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually IntegerType.
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType(SchemaUtils.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:51)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.Classifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ProbabilisticClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$LogisticRegressionParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:265)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:100)
  ... 48 elided
```

Let's fix `lr` to use `features` column.

Please note that `features` column is the default so I simply create a new instance of `LogisticRegression` (I *could* also use `setInputCol`).

```
val lr = new LogisticRegression()

// it works but I've got no label column (with 0s and 1s and hence the issue)
// the main issue was fixed though, wasn't it?
scala> lr.fit(features)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "label" does not exist.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:266)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:266)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:265)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkNumericType(SchemaUtils.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PredictorParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Predictor.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.Classifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(Classifier.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifier.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$ProbabilisticClassifierParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.ProbabilisticClassifierParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(ProbabilisticClassifier.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.org$apache$spark$ml$classification$LogisticRegressionParams$$super$validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:265)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.validateAndTransformSchema(LogisticRegression.scala:278)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.transformSchema(Predictor.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:100)
  ... 48 elided
```

### Using Multiple Columns

After the first version of the question has been updated, another issue has turned up.

```
scala> va.transform(training)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type StringType is not supported.
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$transformSchema$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler$$anonfun$transformSchema$1.apply(VectorAssembler.scala:117)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transformSchema(VectorAssembler.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transform(VectorAssembler.scala:54)
  ... 48 elided
```

The reason is that [VectorAssembler accepts the following input column types: all numeric types, boolean type, and vector type](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler). It means that one of the columns used for `VectorAssembler` is of StringType type.

In your case the column is `label` since it's of `StringType`. See the schema.

```
scala> training.printSchema
root
 |-- bc: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- pmi: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sv: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- h: double (nullable = true)
 |-- rh: double (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
```

Remove it from your columns to use for VectorAssembler and the error goes away.

If however this or any other column should be included but is of incorrect type, you have to cast it appropriately (provided it is possible by the values the column holds). Use [cast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@cast(to:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) method for this.

> **cast(to: String): Column** Casts the column to a different data type, using the canonical string representation of the type. The supported types are: `string`, `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `date`, `timestamp`.

The error message should include the column name(s), but currently it does not so I filed [SPARK-21285 VectorAssembler should report the column name when data type used is not supported|https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21285] to fix it. Vote for it if you think it's worth to have in the upcoming Spark version.

Comment: Don't include `label` column in your columns for `VectorAssembler`. Please also **not** change your code in your question as that may change the initial version to the point that my answer becomes obsolete (even though it helped initially). Please edit your question and add more content below. Thanks.

Comment: Replace `.setOutputCol("label")` with `.setOutputCol("features")` since you want to create a new column with features (and `label` is already included). Also, `label` column should be of numeric type. I think it should be `0` or `1` so your `T` or `F` should be mapped appropriately.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "label" does not exist.
 at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:264)

Comment: After `VectorAssembler` you have to have a training dataset with `label` and `features` columns. Make sure you have them both. Use `printSchema` to know the available fields.